# Why does no slipping occur when a particle is attached to a string, which is wound onto a circular disk, and the system is allowed to move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, rotational-kinematics

[image]

In this question, the only way we can find the angular acceleration of the disc is by equating it to the linear acceleration of the particle divided by the radius. But this holds only if the string moves without slipping.. why is this the case? The only thing I can make out is that it has something to do with there being no friction, but why does no friction imply no slipping? Friction prevents slipping, so no friction should actually mean slipping occurs.

Comment: The question says: *one end of a light inextensible string is **attached to a point on the rim of the disk***. The string cannot slip because it's attached to the disk.

Comment: Why does it being attached imply no slipping? And isn't attaching the string to the disk the only way of making such an object?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to friction, you are correct in that it prevents slipping, but there is no chance for slipping since one end of the rope is attached to the disk itself and it is assumed that the string is wound tightly around the disk. Think of the ball pulling the string and the string pulling the disk (at the point of connection).

The reason the problem restricts the string from slipping or stretching is because, as you point out in your post, the expected technique for solving the problem is to equate the angular acceleration of the disk to the linear acceleration of the ball via introductory relations.

If you want to apply Newton's second law, then note that $\mathbf{\tau}=\mathbf{F}r=I\mathbf{\alpha}$, where $\tau$ is the torque on the disk, $\mathbf{F}$ is the force applied tangent to the disk, $r$ is the radius of the disk, $I$ is the moment of inertia of the disk, and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the disk.

In order for the above relations to hold the string must not be allowed to stretch as such a string would introduce a more complicated relation between the torque applied to the disc and the acceleration of the ball. To convince yourself that a stretchable string is not allowed by the above relations consider the limiting case of an 'infinitely stretchable' string. In this case as soon as the ball was released it would drop to the floor producing no torque on the disc. In other words, the strict coupling of the disc's angular acceleration to the ball's linear acceleration requires strict coupling between the disc and ball themselves.